# Make a Link continue over a hidden node

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a go.js chart that shows a hierarchy flow.
Its more of less like the one in the [chartEditor](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html) example but what I want to do is make some nodes hidden. For example in this chart I would like to make node with id:6 hidden so that I would keep every chart element in their position but have node with id:6 removed.

[image]

I have found out how to hide a node following this ["How to hide nodes?"](https://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-hide-nodes/7282) link but what happens is that after I hide the node I am left with a broken link. Is there a way to fix that? Ideally I would like that link to continue over the hidden node.

[image]

What I did in the code is exacly what it says in the go.js forum answer. I added a "visible", property to the nodeDataArray, and added the following binding to the node's go.Shape object

```
new go.Binding("visible", "visible", function(t) { return t ? true : false; })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to show a vertical line of the appropriate stroke color and width in place of the normal elements.

So, in the node template of the Org Chart Editor sample, replace:

        `// define the node's outer shape
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          {
            name: "SHAPE", fill: "white", stroke: null,
            // set the port properties:
            portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer"
          }),`

with:

        `// define the node's outer shape
        $(go.Panel,
          // this is the vertical line that the user will see when the SHAPE is transparent:
          $(go.Shape, "LineV", { strokeWidth: 4, stroke: "#00a4a4",
                                 alignment: go.Spot.Center, stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill }),
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
            {
              name: "SHAPE", fill: "white", stroke: null, stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill,
              // set the port properties:
              portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer"
            })
        ),`

and add `name: "PANEL"` to the "Horizontal" Panel holding all of the information:

        `$(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
          { name: "PANEL" },
          $(go.Picture,
            . . .`

Then invoke this function, or something like it, when the user wants to make a selected node invisible:

  `function toggle() {
    var node = myDiagram.selection.first();
    if (node instanceof go.Node) {
      myDiagram.startTransaction();
      if (node.isTreeLeaf) {
        node.opacity = (node.opacity > 0.5) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
      } else {
        var shape = node.findObject("SHAPE");
        if (shape !== null) shape.opacity = (shape.opacity > 0.5) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
        var panel = node.findObject("PANEL");
        if (panel !== null) panel.opacity = (panel.opacity > 0.5) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
      }
      myDiagram.commitTransaction("toggled opacity of node elements");
    }
  }`

Note how for leaf nodes it makes the whole node translucent, rather than showing a vertical line.

The result is:
[image: GoJS Org Chart Editor with one node translucent]

By the way, you might get quicker answers by posting in the GoJS forum:
https://forum.nwoods.com/c/gojs